# poetry sys_plattform markers for different mac platforms

Tags: python-poetry

I am trying to use the poetry install package for installing pytorch on mac and I want to specify different wheel files for different platforms.

Pytorch has wheels for intel and ARM based macs. It seems I can specify the intel platform using `markers="sys_platform == 'macosx'"`. How can one specify the arm based system?

I also wonder if `macosx` identifier will select both the platforms? I only have access to intel based mac to do the tests at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

Tested on latest Poetry 1.3.1, I succeed simply using this now:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.10.x"
torch = "1.13.1"
```

Poetry picked right version.

---

### Original Answer

To answer your question, it would be

```
markers = "sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'arm64'"
markers = "sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'x86_64'"
```

Here is final version:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.10.x"
torch = [
  {markers = "sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'arm64'", url = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/b3/eaea3fc35d0466b9dae1e3f9db08467939347b3aaa53c0fd81953032db33/torch-1.13.0-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl"},
  {markers = "sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'x86_64'", url = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/79/ead6840368f294497591af143980372ff956fc4c982c457a8b5610a5a1f3/torch-1.13.0-cp310-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl"},
  {markers = "sys_platform == 'linux'", url="https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/61/b0303b8810c1300e75e8e665d043f6c2b272a4da60e9cc33416cde8edb76/torch-1.13.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl"}
]
```

- `arm64` is for macOS with M1/M2 chip. `x86_64` is for macOS with
  Intel chip.
- For Linux, you can also define `platform_machine` if you are using
  multiple architectures (In the demo above, it is using `aarch64` wheel).

You can find all wheel URLs at either one of

- https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/
- https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files

You can find your current platform and architecture by using Python command:

```
> python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'darwin'
>>> import platform
>>> platform.machine()
'arm64'
```

You can find the list of `sys.platform` at [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform).

(Wish Poetry can be smarter for PyTorch in future so that we do not need manually set them)